# How to catkin_make designated package in the same workspace?

Tags: catkin, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ubuntu: 12.04

ROS: Hydro

Hey, everyone~  I am a freshman to ROS.

The problem occurred when I want to catkin_make only one package in the my workspace.

There are 2 packages, `chapter2_tutorials` and `dynamic_tutorials` in my workspace.

I want to catkin_make one of my packages,

after I run `catkin_make chapter2_tutorials` ,
The terminal shows:

```
+++ processing catkin package: 'chapter2_tutorials'
+++ processing catkin package: 'dynamic_tutorials'
```

I think it obviously shows that it catkin_make both of the packages.

So what should I do to make it?
Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220613/how-to-catkin_make-designated-package-in-the-same-workspace?/) by [ChenJinluo](https://answers.ros.org/users/24992/chenjinluo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2015-11-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

instructions here http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/commands/catkin_make

---

Originally posted by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) with karma: 1504 on 2015-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ChenJinluo](https://answers.ros.org/users/24992/chenjinluo/) on 2015-11-09**:
Thank you very much! I should search it  in Wiki first~